# comparison of two estimators

Tags: estimation, loss-functions, risk, point-estimation, method-comparison

Assume we have a data set $\mathbf{x}_{n} = (x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})$. Let $\delta_{1}(\mathbf{x}_{n})$ and $\delta_{2}(\mathbf{x}_{n})$ be two consistent estimators of some parameter $\theta \in R^{k}$.

To compare the estimators I use quadratic loss: $L(\delta, \theta) = \sum_{i}^{k}(\delta_{i}(\mathbf{x}_{n}) - \theta_{i})^{2}$. I have shown that for  $\delta_{1}(\mathbf{x}_{n})$ and $\delta_{2}(\mathbf{x}_{n})$ the following holds:
$$
P(\underset{n\to\infty}{\liminf} \{L(\delta_{1}(\mathbf{X}_{n}), \theta) \leq L(\delta_{2}(\mathbf{X}_{n}), \theta) \}) = 1.
$$
where for the sequence of events $A_{n}$ the $\underset{n\to\infty}{\liminf} A_{n} = \cup_{n}\cap_{i\geq n}A_{n}$

i.e. there exists $n_{1}$ such that $L(\delta_{1}(\mathbf{X}_{n}), \theta) \leq L(\delta_{2}(\mathbf{X}_{n}), \theta)$ a.s.

Can I claim then that $\delta_{1}$ performs asymptotically better in $l_{2}$-sense?

How is it important to analyse minimax risk in this case?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Do you mean $$P[\underset{n\to\infty}{\liminf} L(\delta_{1}(\mathbf{x}_{n}), \theta) \leq \underset{n\to\infty}{\liminf}L(\delta_{2}(\mathbf{x}_{n}), \theta) ] = 1$$ ?

Comment: no. For the sequence of events $A_{n}$ the $\underset{n\to\infty}{\liminf} A_{n} = \cup_{n}\cap_{i\geq n}A_{n}$. I have edited the question.